# npm installing the wrong version

Tags: angularjs, npm, package.json

After i execute npm install, i see that the version of the typings is 1.0.3. But in my package.json, i wrote the exacty the verion that i want. Any idea what is going on ?
is npm always trying to install the latest ?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
  }
```

When i run :

```
typings -v
1.0.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try remove the ^ and write only:

```
"typings": "0.7.12"
```

Comment: Why is this the solution if `^` means `Minor releases: 1 or 1.x or ^1.0.4`? If you have `"typings": "^0.7.12"`, then you should get the highest version of the middle number (7 in this case) and the first letter of the version (0 in this case) should never be updated, right?